# Blade: how to include a section in one page but not in another

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a report that I present on screen.

*report.blade.php*

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        @yield('content')
    </body>
</html>
```

*report_sub1.blade.php*

```
@extends('reports.report')

@section('content')
    <h1> This is sub section 1 </h1>

    <h1> This is sub section 2 </h1>
@stop
```

I want to include the section 2 in the 1st report but not in the second.
Meaning I have two identical reports, but the one should not print section 2.

How can you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use your `report.blade.php` as a master page. Then use two partials as sub-sections, and use a third partial for `section 1`. Finally include this last partial only where you need it:

**section1.php**

```
<!-- section 1 definition-->
<h1> This is sub section 1 </h1>
```

**report_sub1.blade.php**

```
@extends('reports.report')

@section('content')
     <!-- section 1 included -->
     @include('section1')

     <!-- section 2 included only here--> 
     <h1> This is sub section 2 </h1>  
@stop
```

**report_sub2.blade.php**

```
@extends('reports.report')

@section('content')
     <!-- section 1 included -->
    @include('section1') 

    <!-- section 2 included is not included here-->   
@stop
```

Comment: Moppo, okay, but I get the message above. its in the same folder, but it does not find the file for some reason.

Comment: From the error message it seems it's not finding the view: `interventions` Which view is it ?

Comment: yeah, sorry I renamed it to keep it simple, but yes its interventions.blade.php. and ints in the same folder as the section that uses it. It is used as follows '@include('interventions');'

Comment: got it. sub folders  '@include('reports.content.interventions')'

Comment: @morne : if the answer was useful, please consider accepting / upvoting :)